# TSQL: Dynamic pivot based on varchar values not working correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-pivot

I have 2 tables I’m working with:

- zEaAttributes: Used for the field list
- zEAValues: The data we want to pivot

The results I expect to get will be one row of data like this:

```
Name    Street Address  State   County  Zip
--------------------------------------------
Ajax    ABC 1st Ave.    TX      NULL    NULL
```

But instead, I'm getting 3 rows that look like this:

```
Name    Street Address  State   County  Zip
---------------------------------------------
Ajax    NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    ABC 1st Ave.    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL            TX      NULL    NULL
```

And below is the SQL to create and populate the 2 tables we’re testing with.  Please let me know what I’m doing wrong.

Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[zEaAttributes]
(
    [Ent_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Caption] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[zEaAttributes] ([Ent_Id], [Position], [Caption]) 
VALUES ('3fc25249-6b2a-40e6-839d-7e91b01d989f', 1, 'Name')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[zEaAttributes] ([Ent_Id], [Position], [Caption]) 
VALUES ('3fc25249-6b2a-40e6-839d-7e91b01d989f', 2, 'Street Address')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[zEaAttributes] ([Ent_Id], [Position], [Caption]) 
VALUES ('3fc25249-6b2a-40e6-839d-7e91b01d989f', 3, 'State')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[zEaAttributes] ([Ent_Id], [Position], [Caption]) 
VALUES ('3fc25249-6b2a-40e6-839d-7e91b01d989f', 4, 'County')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[zEaAttributes] ([Ent_Id], [Position], [Caption]) 
VALUES ('3fc25249-6b2a-40e6-839d-7e91b01d989f', 5, 'Zip')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[zEAValues]
(
    [Ent_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Caption] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[zEAValues] ([Ent_Id], [Position], [Caption], [Value]) 
VALUES ('3fc25249-6b2a-40e6-839d-7e91b01d989f', 1, 'Name', N'Ajax')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[zEAValues] ([Ent_Id], [Position], [Caption], [Value]) 
VALUES ('3fc25249-6b2a-40e6-839d-7e91b01d989f', 2, 'Street Address', N'ABC 1st Ave.')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[zEAValues] ([Ent_Id], [Position], [Caption], [Value]) 
VALUES ('3fc25249-6b2a-40e6-839d-7e91b01d989f', 3, 'State', N'TX')

--Get a list of the "Fields" (Columns) 
DECLARE @DynamicColumns AS VARCHAR(max)
 
SELECT @DynamicColumns = COALESCE(@DynamicColumns + ', ', '')
                         + Quotename(Caption)
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Caption, Position
        FROM   zEaAttributes
       ) AS FieldList
       ORDER BY Position
 
--Build the Dynamic Pivot Table Query  
DECLARE @FinalTableStruct AS NVARCHAR(max)
 
SET @FinalTableStruct = 'SELECT ' + @DynamicColumns +
' FROM zEAValues x PIVOT ( MAX( Value ) FOR Caption IN ('
                        + @DynamicColumns + ') ) p ' 
EXECUTE(@FinalTableStruct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 3 rows output will be fixed by adding `GROUP BY [Ent_Id]` to the related query.
Use a query like this for `PIVOT`:

```
SET @FinalTableStruct = 
  'SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT [Ent_Id], [Caption], [Value] FROM zEAValues
  ) x 
  PIVOT 
  ( 
    MAX([Value]) FOR Caption IN (' + @DynamicColumns + ') 
  ) p'
```

By using this query the database engine will utilize `GROUP BY [Ent_Id]` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Different values in the position column is causing `PIVOT` to move the values to the corresponding row. You need to drop the column while doing the operation as it's not needed as per the output.
Following would do that:

```
SET @FinalTableStruct = 'SELECT ' + @DynamicColumns +
                        ' FROM (select caption, [Value] from zEAValues) x 
                        PIVOT 
                        ( 
                            MAX(Value) FOR Caption IN ('+ @DynamicColumns + ')
                        ) p' 
print @FinalTableStruct
EXECUTE(@FinalTableStruct)
```

[image]